# How to check that where in the Spring boot project (Intellij Idea), particular maven dependency is used?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

In the pom.xml file there are many dependencies are added. I want to check one particular dependency is used where in the whole project. I am using Intellij Idea for Spring Boot project. Project is too big to check each file manually.
I want to check where the below dependency is used in the project?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: check the dependency tree, there is a maven command for that.
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

Comment: Remove the dependency --> update project -> build project -> check the compilation errors for direct usage. In case it is a transitive dependency, you can check via `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: @StultuskeThanks for reply! but that tree is redirecting to pom.xml file only. I want to check what is use and where is it used in the other classes, not pom.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways :

First :

CTRL+shift+F and search for "com.google.guava". This will give you all the files where classes from this package has been imported.

Second :

Remove the dependency from pom.xml. And reload your pom changes.

This will remove your library from classpath. As soon as this happens, your IDE will start showing red lines under all the classes where your dependency has been used as it'll not find classes from your library mentioned in imports.